# Create a DocType like Interface, based out of the fields of a Doctype Object - Frappe Python

Tags: python-3.x, doctype, dynamic-forms, frappe

I am currently working on a project based out of Frappe Framework(Python). The requirement is as follows:

1. A DocType named ***Form***, which has a table field type with field as ***DocField***. Basically mimicking the DocType. This is named as ***form_fields***
2. The above ***Form*** stores, different form objects. Each object will be an individual form.
3. Now comes the problem: Need to come up with an interface in Frappe which renders a create form(like DocType object creation), based out of the above ***Form***'s fields ie, ***form_fields***. All other functionalities similar to DocType needs to be implementd as well(update/clone/listing)

Need help with point 3.

Tried a few things for implementing point 3. I guess there is no straightforward way for doing this. Tried out VirtualDocTypes even though they are not used for this actually.

The basic question is "***Need a provision to create objects(db rows) based out of***

> DocType objects

***(as of now we are creating objects based out of DocTypes)***"

In order to implement point 3, which are the modules to look into?
What's the right approach to this?
Is there something I am missing here?